# Partition trigger and serial column concurrence

Tags: postgresql

I'm using the following trigger to auto generate monthly partitions for a given table. It works fine.

```
create or replace function beat_insert_function()
returns trigger as $$

declare
  partition_date text;
  partition_name text;
  start_of_month text;
  end_of_next_month text;

begin
  partition_date := to_char(new.created_at, 'yyyy_mm');
  partition_name := 'beat_' || partition_date;
  start_of_month := to_char((new.created_at), 'yyyy-mm') || '-01';
  end_of_next_month := to_char((new.created_at + interval '1 month'), 'yyyy-mm') || '-01';

  if not exists (select 1 from information_schema.tables where table_name = partition_name) then
    raise notice 'A partition has been created %', partition_name;
    execute format(E'create table %I (check(date_trunc(''day'', created_at) >= ''%s'' and date_trunc(''day'', created_at) < ''%s'')) inherits (public.beat)', partition_name, start_of_month, end_of_next_month);
  end if;

  --- this generates only par keys
  execute format('insert into %I (something) values ($1)', partition_name) using new.something;

  return null;
end

$$
language plpgsql;
```

This trigger is configured to run before insert, like so:

```
create trigger beat_insert_trigger
before insert on beat
for each row execute procedure beat_insert_function();
```

Because the trigger intercepts each insert and the master table contains a `id serial column primary key`, I ended with only par keys (2, 4, 6, 8, etc), so I changed the insert to:

```
  execute format('insert into %I (id_beat, created_at) values (currval(''beat_id_beat_seq''), $1)', partition_name) using new.created_at;
```

Now, the primary key is correct (1, 2, 3, 4, etc)...

My question is: is it safe to use `currval` in the given scenario? Can the table receive another insert before the trigger finishes, thus creating an insert error, or will the session prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is safe, because according to the documentation:

> Because this is returning a session-local value, it gives a predictable answer whether or not other sessions have executed `nextval` since the current session did.

But why don't you do the natural thing and

```
EXECUTE format(
           'insert into %I (id_beat, created_at) values ($1, $2)',
           partition_name)
USING NEW.id_beat, NEW.created_at;
```

Comment: thx. your snippet looks better, i have updated my code